# Do we have any asp vbs complete for vim?

Tags: vim, asp-classic

I see a lot of complete for gvim such as php, c , css, but I can't find any complete form aspvbs

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about auto completion? Do you know about ctags? (http://ctags.sourceforge.net/).

Anyway, here's an OK solution. Well actually i haven't tested it too much yet but it seems to work fairly well. Assuming you are using ctags, add

```
--langmap=Asp:*.vbs
```

to your ~/.ctags file and it will tell ctags to generate tags for your *.vbs files (as Asp, whatever that is =D). I'm don't know much about asp / vbs and their relationship (not sure i want to, hehe), so once again I'm telling you I don't know how well this works. Perhaps someone can fill in on this?

I guess even better... Add your own language (and share with me) : )

http://ctags.sourceforge.net/EXTENDING.html

Answer (score -1):

I don't use Vim much, but 5 seconds of googling turned up this: http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=993 - is that what you're looking for, or something different?

Comment: this is the syntax highlight, but I want to find the keyword autocomplete